# My VS Code is opening Markdown files with a fancy editor with an outline and formatting buttons in a row above the text input

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown

after updated VS Code I got editor on my MD files. Is there a way to disable it?
I already checked my extensions but none of my extension related to this MD editor.
I just want my normal MD file like a text file. I don't want a preview like below image every time I open MD file

[image]

Comment: Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.

Comment: @starball thanks just found the problem its because office viewer extension on vscode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behaviour was found via extension bisect to be caused by the [`cweijan.vscode-office`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cweijan.vscode-office).

If you don't want the extension's behaviour at all, then just disable the extension. Otherwise, look into its contributed settings to see if it offers configuration points to change the behaviour in ways that are desirable to you.